# Tortoise - is it possible to ignore new folder before committing it?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, ignore

I just added a class library project to my .NET solution. When I built it, it created the `bin` and `obj` folders, which I want to exclude from version control.

However, Tortoise won't let me ignore the folders before the first commit. It gives the following message.

> Cannot add bin to the ignore list!

I have to check the whole lot in, and then choose `Delete and add to ignore list` for the two folders.

How do I prevent them being checked in at all, and ensure Tortoise knows to ignore them?

Comment: it's just that you have to add the parent folder first.  the simplest solution is just: put the parent folder in there - but set the contents aside somewhere like on your desktop.   commit the empty parent folder.  now put all the content in the parent folder, and proceed normally.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

It's because you haven't yet added their parent directories.  Do 'add' on the new project directory first, and then when it gives you the dialog showing the list of files to add, untick `bin` and `obj`.  You can then ignore them once the project directory has been added.

You could also add `bin` and `obj` to your global ignore list (in the TortoiseSVN prefs) though that will ignore *any* instances of `bin` across all your projects.

Comment: Oh, I see. So just check the project in EXCEPT the bin and obj folders, then ignore them in the usual way. Thank you.

Comment: You can just add the project, and then once it's added (you don't need to commit yet) you can ignore them.

Answer (score 9):

Set the `svn:ignore` property to "bin" and "obj" for the *parent folder*, *provided the parent folder is under version control*.

- Right-click the parent folder in Explorer
- Choose TortoiseSVN -> Properties
- Choose the `svn:ignore` property from the "Property name" drop-down
- Add "bin" and "obj" to the "Property value" field, separating them by line breaks.
- Commit the parent folder **only**
- The child folders should show up with a grey "ignored" icon from then on.

Comment: How do I do that using Tortoise?

Comment: @David the parent folder needs to be under version control in this scenario by the way.

Answer (score 3):

you can add to your global ignore pattern.

In Tortoise settings, on the General pane, there's a edit field to add global ignore patterns. These are wildcard-enabled so you can add all the temporary files, eg *.ncb etc, but also directories.

eg. here's my global ignore pattern, you can see it's set to ignore many file types but also a couple of directories.

```
*.dep *.aps *.vbw *.suo *.obj *.ncb *.plg *.bsc *.ilk *.exp *.sbr *.opt *.pdb *.idb *.pch *.res *.scc *.vspscc *\bin\Release *\Debug *\obj *.user BuildLog.htm *.cache *.log *.dep *.intermediate.manifest *ReSharper*
```